# Firebase deploy fails because of Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2

Tags: firebase, nuxt.js, vite, nitro

I upgraded to the latest version of Nuxt3, it work perfectly on local, build with no errors, but when trying to deploy on Firebase, it throws this error, does anyone have an idea why, or where it might come from?

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Here's my config:

```
------------------------------
- Operating System: `Darwin`
- Node Version:     `v16.20.0`
- Nuxt Version:     `3.2.3`
- Nitro Version:    `2.2.3`
- Package Manager:  `npm@8.19.4`
- Builder:          `vite`
- User Config:      `typescript`, `ssr`, `nitro`, `runtimeConfig`, `modules`, `i18n`, `pinia`, `css`, `build`, `vite`, `hooks`, `app`
- Runtime Modules:  `@pinia/nuxt@0.4.7`, `@nuxtjs/i18n@8.0.0-beta.10`
- Build Modules:    `-`
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

As an interim solution you could do the following.

1. Build the server with nuxi
   `npx nuxi build`
2. Go to the build output directory (default: `.output/server`)
3. Edit package.json, remove fsevent@2.3.2 from dependencies section, then add
   `"optionalDependencies": { "fsevents": "*" }`
4. Deploy to your target, in my case `firebase deploy`